# How to view multiple inboxes on Apple Watch (individually)

Tags: email, apple-watch

It seems like in the iPhone's Watch app for email I can select one and only one mailbox to read from the Watch (Include Mail setting). I really dislike the "All Inboxes" concept, but would like to have two of my four inboxes available, along with a sub-folder or two. Is that possible with the stock Mail app? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Apple Watch user box (https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1708/en_US/apple_watch_user_guide.pdf): "Choose which mailbox appears on Apple Watch. Open the Apple Watch app on iPhone, tap My Watch, then go to Mail > Include Mail. You can specify only one mailbox, although if you don’t choose a mailbox, you’ll see content from all inboxes."